# "TypeError: load() takes at most 1 positional arguments (2 given)" in a Pickle package

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

I am trying to run this code, and getting an error:

> TypeError: load() takes at most 1 positional arguments (2 given)

Code:

```
'''
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

import jsonify

import requests

import pickle

import numpy as np

import sklearn

model = pickle.load(open("lr.pkl"),"rb")

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])

def Home():
return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])

def predict():

gender = 1
    
if request.method == 'POST':

        SeniorCitizen = request.form['SeniorCitizen']
        Partner = request.form['Partner']
        Dependents = int(request.form['Dependents'])
        gender == request.form['Male']
        if (gender == 'Male'):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
        if (Partner == 'Yes'):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
        if (SeniorCitizen == 'Yes'):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
        
        prediction = model.predict([['gender', 'SeniorCitizen', 'Partner', 'Dependents']])
        output = prediction([0])
        if (output == 1):
            return render_template('index.html',prediction_texts = " This customer is going away")
        else:
            return render_template('index.html',prediction_texts = " This customer is NOT going away")
        
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()'''
```

**Associated HTML Code**

```
<body>

    <div style="color:blue">
        <form action="{{ url_for('predict')}}" method="post">
            <h2>Telecom Churn</h2>
            <h3> Are you Senior Citizen?</h3><br><select name='SeniorCitizen' id='SeniorCitizen' required = "required">
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
                </select>
            <h3>What is your Gender?</h3><br><select name="gender" id="gender" required="required">
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
            </select>
            <h3>Do you have any dependents</h3><br><select name="Dependents" id="Dependents" required="required">
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
            <h3>Do you have a Partner?</h3><br><select name="Partner" id="Partner" required="required">
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
            
            <br><br><button id="sub" type="submit ">Calculate the Selling Price</button>
            <br>




        </form>



        <br><br><h3>{{ prediction_text }}<h3>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change: `model = pickle.load(open("lr.pkl"),"rb")`

To: `model = pickle.load(open("lr.pkl","rb"))`

Open should have 2 arguments, but because you misplaced the `)`, you passed 2 arguments into `.load()`.